# How to fix this error discord python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('!kick') and (roleLFJob in message.author.roles or roleLFAba in message.author.roles):
    await client.delete_message(message)
    serverchannel = '405090256124248065'
    messageParsed = message.content.split()
    kick = messageParsed[0]
    mention = messageParsed[1]
    msg = messageParsed[2:]
    for member in message.mentions:
        await client.kick(member)
        await client.send_message(discord.Object(id=serverchannel), '{0} was kicked by {1}, with reason:"**'.format(member.mention, message.author.mention) + msg + '**"')
```

When I wrote this command in discord:

```
!kick @(member.mention) reason, reason and reason
```

This error occur:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Users\senuk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)   
File "overmind.py", line 128, in on_message
    await client.send_message(discord.Object(id=serverchannel), '{0} was kicked by {1} with reason:"**'.format(member.mention, message.author.mention) + msg + '**"') 
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Use str(msg) instead msg in your format string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you typed this:

```
!kick @(member.mention) reason, reason and reason
```

Then when you split the whole content:

```
messageParsed = message.content.split()
kick = messageParsed[0]
mention = messageParsed[1]
msg = messageParsed[2:]
```

The results will be:

```
kick = "!kick"
mention = "@(member.mention)"
msg = ["reason,", "reason", "and", "reason"]
```

On the last line of your code, you tried to concatenate two strings with msg (list). Which isn't possible.

What you probably want is the `msg` to be a string, therefore you should use:

```
msg = " ".join(messageParsed[2:])
```

Which remakes `msg` back to its original form:

```
msg = "reason, reason and reason"
```